# Elasticsearch Auto complete/Suggestion query on korean/chinese/japanese language

Tags: elasticsearch, autocomplete

Is is possible to implement a suggestion query in Elasticsearch for non-english languages like korean, chinese, japanese etc..??

I tried using ICU Analysis plugin. Though the ICU tokenizers able to tokenize the non-english languages, it was not helping me out while doing a suggestion / Auto complete query.

Answer (score 0):

Chinese lanugage :
 we have Smartcn plugin that can be installed to elasticsearch.

Japanese Language :
 Using Korumoji plugin we can analyze and run queries on Japanese language.